# Using `chunk` to make look-and-say sequence

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Given a string of numbers `string = "1112322"`, I am trying to return the look-and-say sequence associated with it: Three `"1"`s give `"31"`, one `"2"` gives `"12"`, etc., so result would be `"31121322"`.

I would like to do it in the following way:

- Break up the string into `["1","1","1","2","3","2","2"]`.
- Chunk them using the identity block `{|n| n}`. This should return the data

  ```
  {1<=[1,1,1],2<=[2],3<=[3],2<=[2,2]}
  ```

  as an enumerable object.
- Map them to `"31"`, `"12"`, etc. (the length of the value array as string + the key).
- Join the whole array into a string.

Can anyone explain why my following code isn't working?

```
string.split("").chunk { |i| i }.map {|i,array| array.length.to_s+i}.join
```

Comment: What do you mean by *isn't working*? What is the value of `string`?

Comment: By `<=` in the return data, do you mean `=>`?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. Your code does work. It returns `"31121322"`.

Comment: Chunk is awesome. I like the conciseness of the syntax. And the code works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @sawa said, and other have confirmed, your code works just fine, and for the approach you have adopted, it's precisely how you should do it. Well, maybe not "precisely". You could make a small improvement by replacing `split("")` with `each_char`, as the former returns an unnecessary temporary array whereas the latter returns an enumerator.

The main reason I'm offering an answer, however, is to suggest you instead use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression:

```
"1112322".gsub(/(.)\1*/) { |s| "#{s.size}#{s[0]}" }
  #=> "31121322"
```